# How do you move ALL the data from an old drive to a new drive

Tags: macbook-pro, data-transfer, file-transfer

So, I'm going to replace the drive in a mid-2012 macbook pro with an ssd. What would be the easiest way to transfer all the data (files) from the drive to the ssd? Is it possible to have all the programs transfer over also? Do I have to reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to 'clone' the disk, making an exact duplicate, so that everything is exactly as you left it, but just on a new physical device.

First of all, you need a way of connecting either the SSD as an external device, so that the SSD is connected. You can either get a [SATA to USB cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-SATA-Adapter-Cable-Drives-en-GB-SATA-USB-3-0-converter/dp/B01N2JIQR7), or you can get an ['enclosure'](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Enclosure-External-Adapter-Tool-free/dp/B07NYN9PL6), which is a box to put the drive in.

Next, you have to copy the data. As said, you can use either [SuperDuper!](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or  [CCC (Carbon Copy Cloner)](https://bombich.com), which are purpose-built tools to do the job. I recommend SuperDuper!, just for east of use.

You can also use Apple's Disk Utility, though it's a bit more complicated, and I wouldn't recommend it in the face of alternatives.

Then you just have to physically swap the drives around. You'll have the original HDD as a spare copy, which you can access using the cable.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have an enclosure for the HDD or SSD that you can connect via USB, you could use a tool like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/). (CCC has a 30-day trial and is $39.99 to purchase after that. I've had good experience with CCC, but other free or paid utilities may work better for you.)

The convenient part of using CCC or another utility is that it can make the disk bootable, which is required for swapping the disks like you are asking. If you don't make the disk bootable, it won't boot.

If you don't have an enclosure, you can use an empty external hard drive as a middleman. Use your utility to make a bootable copy of your HDD on your external drive, physically swap out the HDD and SSD, boot to macOS from the external drive, then make a bootable copy from the external drive to the new SSD.

If you don't have an external drive or an enclosure, you may have to reinstall macOS and all your other applications and replace your data.

Comment: Most backup programs will do this, CCC is good as is SuperDuper. But when you pick a utility to do this make sure that it can restore a backup and the restored backup is bootable. Both of the aforementioned do this.

Answer (score 0):

Macs come with an app named "Migration Assistant" that will help you copy all files from an old computer to a new one. There are directions for Migration Assitant located on the internet and a good set of directions is given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350).  This link will also describe the app. This is the Apple Supported method to transfer files from one computer to another. The app is in the Utilities folder which is in the Applications folder. Using the method described by @drivec to connect your drives this should enable you to use this app.